# php query string utf8 not working

Tags: php, utf-8

I am trying to generate a query string. The function works for non utf8 characters, but utf8 characters show up as blank.

function

```
function qs_search($qs) {
  parse_str($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'], $query_string);
  $query_string['search'] = basename($qs);
  return http_build_query($query_string);
}
```

These are the results...

qs_search('regular');

```
index.php?list&search=regular
```

qs_search('Синодальный');

```
index.php?list&search=
```

Comment: Try for experimentation sake to do `utf8_decode(basename($qa))` or `utf8_encode(basename($qa))`.

Comment: I thought `basename()` is for using with paths...To return **the base name of the path**...

Comment: @h2ooooooo That did not work.

Comment: What does `$qs` contain before it goes through `basename()` ? ([It seems to work fine](http://3v4l.org/5aEhG))

Comment: @h2ooooooo it is only defined within the function, it contains no value outside

Comment: @user1766306 Yet you pass it as a parameter. How do you call `qs_search`? **Edit** Ah sorry, misunderstood the OP. Why are you using `basename()`?

Comment: What about changing the line `$query_string['search'] = basename($qs);` to this: `$query_string['search'] = urlencode($qs);`

Comment: Works fine here. What PHP version/system is this on? Can you reproduce any similar problems on the same system? Can you try the same code on another system?

Comment: i think your problem lies elsewhere. have your PHP files been saved in ansi/ascii perhaps? do you do any other processing with the result of qs_search?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per the comments, I still have no idea why you're using `basename`, however, using [`set_locale`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.setlocale.php) will work in PHP 5.2+:

```
<?php
    function qs_search($qs) {
        $query_string = array();
        $query_string['search'] = basename($qs);
        return http_build_query($query_string);
    }
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "en_US.UTF8");
    var_dump(qs_search("regular"));
    var_dump(qs_search("Синодальный"));
?>
```

[As stated, this will **NOT** work on PHP 5.0.0 - 5.1.6. Click to see results.](http://3v4l.org/6XIa5)

**Edit**:

Apparently the developers of Drupal had the same problem and created [their own `basename` function](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21includes%21file.inc/function/drupal_basename/8) because of [this bug](http://drupal.org/node/278425), and that should fix your issue on PHP 5.0.0 - 5.1.6.

Comment: this fixed my issue `setlocale(LC_ALL, "en_US.UTF8");` thank you :)

Comment: @user1766306 You should edit your apache/PHP config to use this locale though, to make sure that it's used all over your site if it's in UTF8.