# http_build_query with utf-8 encoding

Tags: php

I want to make a post request using file_get_contents. My post data contains Japanese characters. It seems like `http_build_query` is not supporting `utf-8`. I tried to use `http_build_query_utf8`, but it says no method to call. How can I do it?

Comment: Please provide examples. https://3v4l.org/lDOIS seems correct Note `%C2%B5` is the URL encoded value of the mu.

Comment: `$postdata = http_build_query(
    array(
        'name' => '神奈川県'
    )
);`
I'm using this to bind the values. But it sends some unrecognized charset.

Comment: I checked the API using postman, it seems fine there. But I'm trying to make a post request from PHP, but it constantly saying "Unsupported characters". This API only accepts Japanese name.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/13293660/2943403

Comment: I understood but is there any ways to keep it as it is? Actually I'm have to make 3 api calls from single php file.